# How do I include information in the header when calling a web service using http protocol

Tags: java

I’m trying to use the Bitrex api for icons.  In the documentation it states,
`calculate the HMAC hash and include it under an apisign header`.
I was able to calculate the `HMAC hash`, but I do not know how to include it in the header.

Code:

```
     try {
           String httpsURL = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-BTCD";

         httpsURL= cMarkets.mTitle[market]; 
         httpsURL="https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-";
         httpsURL+=cMarkets.mTitle[market];  

            URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
            String Hashcode=new String("####hash####");

            // How do I include the hashcode under apisign in the header??????
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
            InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String inputLine;


            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                reply+=inputLine;
            }
           } catch (Exception e)
           {
               System.out.println("Exception in getting data from server");
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
con.setRequestProperty("apisign", {{your calculated HMAC Hash}});
```